# TypeScript Rest Props - allow any props or tell the component which props they're going to be

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I'm building a React app with TypeScript. I have a `RequiresPermission` component, that based on a predicate, should render one or the other component and forward all props.

```
type Props = {
  NotPermittedComponent: React.ComponentType;
  PermittedComponent: React.ComponentType;
  isPermitted: boolean;
};

const RequiresPermisson = ({
  NotPermittedComponent,
  PermittedComponent,
  isPermitted,
  ...rest
}: Props) =>
  isPermitted ? (
    <PermittedComponent {...rest} />
  ) : (
    <NotPermittedComponent {...rest} />
  );

export default RequiresPermisson;
```

When I render the component, TypeScript yells about `RequiresPermission` in:

```
const PERMITTED_TEXT = 'permitted';
const NOT_PERMITTED_TEXT = 'not-permitted';

type TestPropsProps = {
  text: string;
};

const NotPermittedTestComponent: React.FunctionComponent<TestPropsProps> = ({
  text,
}) => (
  <div>
    <span>{NOT_PERMITTED_TEXT}</span>
    {text}
  </div>
);

const PermittedTestComponent: React.FunctionComponent<TestPropsProps> = ({
  text,
}) => (
  <div>
    <span>{PERMITTED_TEXT}</span>
    {text}
  </div>
);

const createProps = ({
  NotPermittedComponent = NotPermittedTestComponent,
  PermittedComponent = PermittedTestComponent,
  isPermitted = false,
  text = 'foo',
} = {}) => ({
  NotPermittedComponent,
  PermittedComponent,
  isPermitted,
  text,
});

const props = createProps();
render(<RequiresPermission {...props} />);
```

saying:

```
Type '{ NotPermittedComponent: FunctionComponent<TestPropsProps>; PermittedComponent: FunctionComponent<TestPropsProps>; isPermitted: boolean; text: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ NotPermittedComponent: ComponentType<{}>; PermittedComponent: ComponentType<{}>; isPermitted: boolean; }'.
  Types of property 'NotPermittedComponent' are incompatible.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<TestPropsProps>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
      Type 'FunctionComponent<TestPropsProps>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<TestPropsProps>'.
            Property 'text' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'TestPropsProps'.
```

I also tried `Record<string, unknown>` as `props` but that doesn't work either.

How can you fix this to either pass the props or allow any (not the type `any`) props so the `...rest` parameter works?

Comment: *"allow any props"* - `(props: any) => ...`? `unknown` makes more sense as a *return* type than a parameter type.

Comment: since you are not accepting any answer, I would assume something is missing. Could you give any feedback on what part of your question hasn't been answered or why it does not fit your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but I have just combined all the prop types. This gives you type checking for all the props. I have to forward all the props because I can not make sure something like `isPermitted` is not required on a sub component.

```
interface Props <A, B>{
  NotPermittedComponent: React.ComponentType<A>;
  PermittedComponent: React.ComponentType<B>;
  isPermitted: boolean;
}

const RequiresPermisson = <A, B>(props: Props<A, B> & A & B): JSX.Element => {
  const {
    NotPermittedComponent,
    PermittedComponent,
    isPermitted,
  } = props
  return isPermitted ? (
    <PermittedComponent {...props} />
  ) : (
    <NotPermittedComponent {...props} />
  )
}
```

Comment: A this one is awesome! Why do you need both `<A, B>` and not just `<A>`? @ian

Comment: A and B are just the props of PermittedComponent and NotPermittedComponent, since it was asked for them to be different, we need different types for them. A and B will get inferred from the components you insert and all of them will be needed/possible on RequiersPermission. @Gabriel

Comment: I accepted the answer because at least it compiles, but technically there is another problem. `PermittedComponent` and `NotPermittedComponent` now get themselves and `isPermitted` passed as props into them, but those are not their props. Do you have any fix for that?

Comment: I understand you concern. But even with the `...rest` from your code you will give `PermittedComponent` also the props of `NotPermittedComponent`. And what if I write a `PermittedComponent` that has `isPermitted` as a prop. Im not sure there is a way to separate all those without isolating the props into something like `permittedComponentProps` or passing them as renderProps.

Answer (score 0):

You need generic types from typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

In short, these are dynamic types that depends on what is inputted.

In the code below, we assign all props that are passed to the type T, and tell typescript that the props are: required props `NotPermittedComponent`
`PermittedComponent`
`isPermitted` along with all of the `rest`, which in this case becomes the type T.

```
type Props = {
  NotPermittedComponent: React.ComponentType;
  PermittedComponent: React.ComponentType;
  isPermitted: boolean;
};

const RequiresPermisson = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>({
  NotPermittedComponent,
  PermittedComponent,
  isPermitted,
  ...rest
}: Props & T) =>
  isPermitted ? (
    <PermittedComponent {...rest} />
  ) : (
    <NotPermittedComponent {...rest} />
  );

export default RequiresPermisson;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code it throws same error:

`Types of property 'NotPermittedComponent' are incompatible.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<TestProps>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
      Type 'FunctionComponent<TestProps>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
        Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<TestProps>'.
            Property 'text' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type 'TestProps'.`

Comment: Jeez this is complicated stuff. Been trying to build a way of passing any component as `PermittedComponent` and `NotPermittedComponent`, and require to pass all and only props on the `RequiresPermisson` component. Been looking all around internet and does not seem to be a way AFAIK. The problem is the dynamic props of `PermittedComponent` and `NotPermittedComponent` , do these ALWAYS only contain only {text: string}? In that case I'd be really simple.

Comment: I know right  Thanks for using your weekend to help me btw, really appreciate it  I also have spend hours on this and couldn't find a way to make this work. No, the PermittedComponent and the NotPermittedComponent can even contain both different props (so one `{ myNumber: number }` and the other `{ myBool: boolean }`).

Comment: `type PropsOf<T> = T extends React.ComponentType<infer Props> ? Props : never` I saw this was used somewhere to get the props of passed components, and I tried things like `const RequiresPermisson = <
  P extends Record<"PermittedComponent" | "NotPermittedComponent", unknown>
>({`, and hoped this could make me add `PropsOf<P["PermittedComponent"]>` as required props. Could get it to work dynamically :/